# Non-maximum suppression in corner detection

Tags: python, opencv

I am writing a Harris Corner Detection algorithm in Python, and am up to performing non-max suppression in order to detect the corner points.

I have found the corner response function `R` which appears to be accurate when I print it out, however I do not know where to go from here. I roughly understand the concept of non-max suppression, i.e. taking the pixel with the highest intensity within a window, setting that as the corner point and the rest to 0. Though I am not sure how to go about this in regard to implementation.

After calculating it, would I then use the map it creates to set those pixels within the original image to a particular color (to indicate which are corners)?

My code so far is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load image
img = cv2.imread('mountains.jpg')

# Make a copy of the image
img_copy = np.copy(img)

# Convert image from BGR to RGB
img_copy = cv2.cvtColor(img_copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Convert to grayscale for filtering
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_copy, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Copy grayscale and convert to float32 type
gray_1 = np.copy(gray)
gray_1 = np.float32(gray_1)
img_1 = np.copy(img)

# Compute derivatives in both x and y directions
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray_1, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=5)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray_1, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=5)

# Determine M = [A C ; C B] performing element-wise multiplication
A = np.square(sobelx)
B = np.square(sobely)
C = np.multiply(sobelx, sobely)

# Apply gaussian filter to matrix components
gauss = np.array([[1, 2, 1],
                  [2, 4, 2], 
                  [1, 2, 1]])/16

A_fil = cv2.filter2D(A, cv2.CV_64F, gauss)
B_fil = cv2.filter2D(B, cv2.CV_64F, gauss)
C_fil = cv2.filter2D(C, cv2.CV_64F, gauss)

# Calculate determinant
det = A_fil * B_fil - (C_fil ** 2)

# Calculate trace (alpha = 0.04 to 0.06)
alpha = 0.04
trace = alpha * (A_fil + B_fil) ** 2

# Using determinant and trace, calculate corner response function
R = det - trace

# Display corner response function
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20,10))

ax1.set_title('Corner response fuction')
ax1.imshow(R, cmap="gray")
```

(Note: Stack overflow images were not working properly)

Output:

[image: Output]

Using OpenCV's Harris Corner Detection:

[image: OpenCV]

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while so you likely already have your answer but since no one has responded yet, I'll leave this for posterity.

Here is a simple algorithm for non-max suppression:

- partition your image into tiles (e.g. 64 x 48 pixels)
- choose a minimum separation space (e.g. >= 10 pixels between features)
- choose a max number of features per tile (such as 5)

Sort your features in each window tile by R (highest to lowest) and then only accept (at most) 5 largest features that are at least 10 pixels away from other features. You won't be able to guarantee a minimum 10px distance across window tiles but this is a reasonable start.